# "Transaction is invalid" when switching to PayPal live

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I'm using the .NET PayPal SDK to integrate the REST API in a legacy ASP.NET website. I had no problem with all the development in sandbox mode, but as soon as I switch to live mode I keep getting this error:

```
This transaction is invalid. Please return to the recipient's website to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow.
```

I've found Q&A for a similar error, but they all were about NVP API, and the problem was usually related to SetExpressCheckout. This is not apparently my case.

Of course, I've already checked the credentials. I can get an access token, I get no exceptions, it's just that the PayPal popup redirects to "hermes/fallback".

Is there something I can do, at least to get a more meaningful error message?

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave it here for future reference.

It was a silly mistake on my part: I did switch to "live" in the dedicated Web.config section, but I left a "sandbox" (instead of "production") in the javascript that called `paypal.Button.render`.